# setTextFilterEnabled(true) : not working

Tags: android

I have a listview application. When I run the application, `setTextFilterEnabled()` is working because there is a keyboard. I installed this application into a real Android phone. `setTextFilterEnabled()` is not working because of no keyboard. How it will work? The phone contains only four buttons and no keybord. How this is possble?

Or what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try holding down the menu button. This brings up the virtual keyboard. If that works, you can give your users a hint (for example, using a `Toast`) that they can do that. Or, you can provide a button somewhere that pops open the virtual keyboard (have a look at [`InputMethodManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html)).